# Looking for a specific lecture

Tags: javascript, animation, real-time

I'm looking for a specific programming/software development lecture that the speaker talks about realtime feedback from the code to the result.
He shows how he changes the code and the result (A generated tree) changes in realtime.
He also changes variables values in the code using the mouse scroll wheel.

He showed a software that he wrote about editing animations (A leaf falling)
He also showed a software that he wrote, a visualizing the "predator prey formula"

I also know that he used to work for Apple

Anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about Bret Victor's "Inventing on principle". Maybe off topic for stack overflow, but it's really interesting:

http://vimeo.com/36579366